# Spectre variant 2 is not supported by hardware

Tags: cpu, vmware, intel

I've installed the latest Intel microcode update to use Spectre variant #2 fix, but [Spectre&Meltdown checker](https://github.com/speed47/spectre-meltdown-checker) still shows that IBRS/IBPB cannot be used.

```
CVE-2017-5715 [branch target injection] aka 'Spectre Variant 2'
* Mitigation 1
  * Kernel is compiled with IBRS/IBPB support:  YES
  * Currently enabled features
    * IBRS enabled for Kernel space:  NO
    * IBRS enabled for User space:  NO
    * IBPB enabled:  NO
* Mitigation 2
  * Kernel has branch predictor hardening (arm):  NO
  * Kernel compiled with retpoline option:  NO
  * Kernel compiled with a retpoline-aware compiler:  NO
> STATUS:  VULNERABLE  (Your kernel is compiled with IBRS but your CPU microcode is lacking support to successfully mitigate the vulnerability)
```

dmesg shows that the latest revision is installed.

```
# dmesg | grep microcode
[    1.199842] microcode: CPU0 sig=0x206d7, pf=0x1, revision=0x713
[    1.199860] microcode: CPU1 sig=0x206d7, pf=0x1, revision=0x713
[    1.199877] microcode: CPU2 sig=0x206d7, pf=0x1, revision=0x713
[    1.199898] microcode: CPU3 sig=0x206d7, pf=0x1, revision=0x713
[    1.199966] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.01 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
```

The CPU is `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2420 0 @ 1.90GHz` and host type is `ESXi-5.1.0-20130402001-standard`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ESXi versions older than 5.5 don’t support the necessary features for hypervisor pass-through of IBPB and IBRS. See [the VMware KB entry](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/52085) for details.

To mitigate Spectre variant 2, you need to either upgrade ESXi, or switch to a retpoline-enabled kernel.

Comment: After upgrading ESXi to 6.5 everything works well, thanks.